# How do we end with GenTraversableOnce in flatMap method?

Tags: scala

Here is the signature for `flatMap`:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

For example `it:Iterable[Option[T]]` can be converted to `Iterable[T]` calling:

```
it.flatMap(x => x)
```

So `That` is `Iterable[T]`, but what is then `B`, and how does `x => x : (Option[T] => Option[T])` correspond to `f` ???

Comment: [Related](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html). I'll let someone who understands the standard library better write this into a proper answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is `Option[T]`, `B` is `T`

There is implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable`, which is a subtype of `GenTraversableOnce`.

Comment: And what is `that`?

Comment: So `A  => B` is ok for `C => D` whenever implicit conversions of `B` to `D` and `A` to `C` exist...

Comment: `That` is `Iterable[T]`. `flatMap(x => x)` is basically the `flatten` function that converts `F[F[A]]` to `F[A]`.

Comment: No, you can't pass `A => B` to some function that expects `C => D`, unless `A` is a supertype of `C`, and `B` is a subtype of `D`. For example, you can't pass an `x => x: Option[T] => Option[T]` to a function which expects `Option[T] => Iterable[T]`. When you call `it.flatMap(x => x)`, the second `x` is implicit converted to `Iterable`, so the type of `x => x` is in fact `Option[T] => Iterable[T]`.

Comment: Implicit conversion was the missing element:) I agree that `Option` is equivalent to either empty iteratively or the one with single element. Why cannot we use `Iterator[B]` instead of `That` in the signature, and how is real type of `That` inferenced?

Comment: Because it makes functions like `map` and `flatMap` more general. For example, `flatMap` on an `Iterable` doesn't necessarily return an `Iterable` - you can make it return a `List`. Similarly, you can `map` on a `List[(A, B)]` and get a `Map[A, B]`.